# Make GHC accept Main module with a main function that isn't IO ()

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there some way (flag or hack) to make GHC accept a main module where the main function's signature isn't `IO ()`? For [Fay](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fay) the main functions have the type `Fay ()`, but GHC does not accept this if the module is Main (or the module name is left out).

Comment: What problem should this solve? Are you concerned about security?

Comment: The issue is that we use GHC for typechecking, which works fine except for the `Main.main` case where we use the type `Fay ()` since we do not have an IO monad.

Comment: You could insert a `dummy :: IO ()` and compile with `-main-is Main.dummy`.

Comment: Maybe you don't even need to insert the dummy if you use something like -main-is Some.Completely.Different.Dummy.Module ?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen nice, sounds perfect! I will try it out.

Comment: Sorry for being slow on testing this. @DanielFischer and Ørjan Johansen, this works perfectly, thanks! Please add an answer so I can accept it! Not sure who to award the answer to :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The entry point to the programme must have type `IO a` for some `a`, and as far as I know, there is no way to make GHC accept other types (without modifying its source code).

By default the entry point is `Main.main`, but you can specify different actions as entry points using the `-main-is` flag with GHC. The general form is

```
ghc -main-is Module.action ModuleThatImportsEverything.hs -o programme
```

You can omit the `Module` part if the module is `Main`,

```
ghc -main-is action ModuleThatImportsEverything.hs -o programme
```

or the `action`part, if its name is `main`,

```
ghc -main-is Module ModuleThatImportsEverything.hs -o programme
```

is equivalent to `-main-is Module.main`.

For your case, you can add a dummy action to the `Main` module, or a dummy module - that of course needs to be imported (directly or indirectly) from the `Main` module - to the programme to stand in as the entry point as far as GHC is concerned.